# Need help sorting similar values in dictionary into one

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

I have a json file with a certain output format.

```json
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Zvezdelina",
                    "last_name": "Stankova",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=375269",
                    "helpfullness": 4.3,
                    "clarity": 4.3,
                    "overall_rating": 4.3
                }
            ],
            "course_name": "CHEM 1",
            "course_mentioned_times": 37
        },
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Alan",
                    "last_name": "Shabel",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1309831",
                    "helpfullness": 3.9,
                    "clarity": 3.5,
                    "overall_rating": 3.7
                }
            ],
            "course_name": "CHEMISTRY 5467",
            "course_mentioned_times": 32
        },
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Kurt",
                    "last_name": "Spreyer",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=706268",
                    "helpfullness": 3.8,
                    "clarity": 3.6,
                    "overall_rating": 3.7
                }
            ],
            "course_name": "ESPM 50",
            "course_mentioned_times": 18
        },
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Kurt",
                    "last_name": "Spreyer",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=706268",
                    "helpfullness": 3.8,
                    "clarity": 3.6,
                    "overall_rating": 3.7
                }
            ],
            "course_name": "ESPM 56",
            "course_mentioned_times": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

As shown in the output for instance we have in total of four ['course_name'] there. They are 'CHEM 1', 'CHEMISTRY 5467','ESPM 56','ESPM 50' with 'course_mentioned_times. So what I don't get is how do I go through all my courses_name key in my json file. Take the MOST mentioned courses out from each classes for instance in this case. I'd want just CHEM 1 and it's attributes  because it is mentioned 56 times clearly more than CHEMISTRY 5476 and I'd like ESPM 50 because it is mentioned 18 times more than ESPM 56 which is only mentioned 17 times. So I'd like my output to have these 2 classes with all their attributes. The comparison should be done by the first letters only skipping the integer for instance just CHEM and CHEMISTRY, however in my output I'd like full name instead of just prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

The below code snippet will update the json file with courses with most mentioned times:

```
import json

# Reading the json data from the source file = data.json
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

temp_data = data
greater = []
len1 = len(data['courses'])
len2 = len1

for i in range(0,len1):
    for j in range(0, len2):
        if i==j:
            continue
        if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][0] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][0]:
            if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][1] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][1]:
                if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][2] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][2]:
                    if data['courses'][i]['course_mentioned_times']> temp_data['courses'][j]['course_mentioned_times']:
                        greater.append(i)
                    else:
                        greater.append(j)


final = []
for i in greater:
  if i not in final:
    final.append(i)

list_order = []

for i in range(0,len(data['courses'])):
    list_order.append(i)

new_final = []
for i in list_order:
    if i not in final:
        new_final.append(i)

for i in new_final:
    if i!=new_final[0]:
        i=i-1
    data['courses'].pop(i)

# Writing the new json data back to data.json file.
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The output of the sample data that you provided after running my solution would be like below:

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "professors": [
        {
          "first_name": "Zvezdelina",
          "last_name": "Stankova",
          "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=375269",
          "helpfullness": 4.3,
          "clarity": 4.3,
          "overall_rating": 4.3
        }
      ],
      "course_name": "CHEM 1",
      "course_mentioned_times": 37
    },
    {
      "professors": [
        {
          "first_name": "Kurt",
          "last_name": "Spreyer",
          "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=706268",
          "helpfullness": 3.8,
          "clarity": 3.6,
          "overall_rating": 3.7
        }
      ],
      "course_name": "ESPM 50",
      "course_mentioned_times": 18
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. My question is that. I have a key called 'courses' with the value is class. So in my json file I have multiple courses names and how many times they were mentioned. 
  "course_name": "CHEMISTRY 5467",
  "course_mentioned_times": 32
I have multiple courses like  CHEM 452, CHEMISTRY 1234,CHEM 7634. I'd like to compare "CHEM", CHEMISTRY and CHEM They are all same. So what I want to do is just append the most "course mentioned times" into my array and all it's attributes such as professors etc.

Comment: for eg: In the code you gave, CHEM 1 and CHEMISTRY 5467 are the same right? and you want to just append the value of the course with highest course mentioned times in the array, which in this case would be CHEM 1 with 37 views. and delete CHEMISTRY 5467. Am i right ??

Comment: Exactly!. So like the way we see if they are same courses are not is by comparing "CHEM" and "CHEMISTRY". If the letter are same or looks same. Then just append the highest views and delete the other one.

Comment: Also I'd want CHEM 1 with 37 views attributes. By attributes I mean everything that's on professors array.

Comment: Tried your snippet!     data['courses'].pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range 
It throws me an index error.

Comment: J padyatti Don't worry about it.